# Is the indescribable a paradox?

Tags: ontology, paradox

The indescribable is that which has no description; yet the term indescribable describes this.

Is this a properly paradox? Or can we say that the word 'indescribable' is a label and has no positive content? But this doesn't seem to be right either...

Comment: There used to be a snack ... wait here it is, it's a Mounds candy bar. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mounds_%28candy%29. Their slogan was "indescribably delicious." So they were using the word "indescribable" as a superlative. It's so good you can't describe how good it is.

Comment: @user4894: Bertrand Russell worked on a theory if descriptions; which presumably began with Aristotle in terms of properties, primary and secondary wrt substances.

Comment: I would call 'indescribable' a description as long as the entity truly is indescribable, like Kant's 'thing-in-itself'' or Lao Tsu's Tao. The word 'indescribable' proscribes the entity and defines Tao by negation. yet this could still be called a description. Probably a matter of opinion.  . , .   . .

Answer (score 1):

English, like all natural languages, is a fuzzy construct with inexact definitions.  One would need a more rigorous language (such as mathematics) to be particularly comfortable with it being a "proper paradox."

> Describe - give an account in words of (someone or something), including all the relevant characteristics, qualities, or events.

I would argue, by this definition, "The indescribable is that which has no description" fails to be a description, because there are clearly characteristics or qualities of an indescribable thing for which the speaker feels they fail to fully capture.

Your second description could be thought of as valid.  In purely mathematical terms, you could define a predicate Describable(x) which returns true if "x" is describable, and then declare the set known as "The Indescribable" to be the set {x | x ϵ , ¬Describable(x)}.  You could then go to show that it is not an empty set by one method or another.  However, this would be a non-constructive proof, which limits the situations it can be applied.  The English equivalent of this is exactly as you say, a "label."  The label "indescribable" is sufficiently described as to not be indescribable, but the contents to which that label is applied are not sufficiently described.

Answer (score 0):

Don't take language seriously.  It's so fuzzy and ambiguous that it can easily spawn a lot of non-problems that will waste your time.  There's a reason a lot of philosophy focuses on language -- from Berkley to Wittgenstein -- many philosophers realized the trap of language.

For instance, what exactly does indescribable mean?  I can think of 3 meanings off the top of my head, each of which can lead to an entirely different answer to your question....

1. Having properties we cannot describe (due to limitations of language
   or shared experience)?  Ineffable may be a better choice of term.
2. Properties that are not sensory (I won't even say if this is
   coherent)?
3. Literally incapable of being described?

Only when you get to #3 can you start to ask if this is a genuine paradox.